# SIGABRT in XCode when trying to init a NSURL path

Tags: ios, objective-c, sigabrt

I've been stuck on this for a while. Does anyone have an idea on why I keep on getting a Signal Abort (SIGABRT) in Xcode with the following code? I'm using Fuse Tools to create my app and what this block does is re-size an image before uploading. The error is on the third line down where `imageFileURL` is. I also included a screenshot. Any help is appreciated.

```
+(NSArray*) getImageSize:(NSString*)path {
    CGFloat width = 0.0f, height = 0.0f;
    NSURL *imageFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    CFURLRef url = (__bridge CFURLRef) imageFileURL;
    CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url, nil);
    if (imageSource == nil) {
        return @[ @( 0 ), @( 0 )];
    }

    CFDictionaryRef imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil);

    CFRelease(imageSource);
```

[image]

Comment: Update your question showing the code that calls `getImageSize:`. My guess is that there is a problem with `path`.

Comment: What is path value?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when `path` is `nil`. You should ensure that the path for this call is never `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the points in comment section but I think in any case path would right then you should check this method.

```
NSURL *imageFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```

instead of it, try to alloc it like

```
NSURL *imageFileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithfileURLWithPath:path];
```

But most probably the path may have the problem.

As per NSURL document statement:
**path**
*The path that the NSURL object will represent. path should be a valid system path, and must not be an empty path. If path begins with a tilde, it must first be expanded with stringByExpandingTildeInPath. If path is a relative path, it is treated as being relative to the current working directory.*

Comment: Both lines of code in this answer are identical. Either works.

Comment: @rmaddy: Agree with it

Comment: Then why does your answer suggest changing that line to the other one? What's the point?

Comment: I am suggesting to change it... My ans is not forcing to change it. This is my way of writing the code so I wrote in my way. If you have seen correctly I have mentioned the problem with URL path as well.